# FTDI. Would need to know more details about the FT_Write() function

Tags: c, windows, send, ftdi

A question about the `FT_Write()` function.

```
FT_STATUS FT_Write (FT_HANDLE ftHandle, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD dwBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpdwBytesWritten)
```

I wonder about the `lpdwBytesWritten`.

When will it ever return `*lpdwBytesWritten < dwBytesToWrite`? Would `FT_Write` return other than `FT_OK` in that case?

And how much data can I send in one call to `FT_Write`? What limit has the `dwBytesToWrite` parameter?

I have not been able to find the answers to these questions. Have read in the [FTDI Knowledgebase](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?ft_write.htm) and also in the [D2XX Programmer's Guide](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf).

Answer (score 3):

`FT_Write` returns  status other than `FT_OK` on "critical" errors.

This function (as well as `FT_Read`) might return `FT_OK` and put in `*lpdwBytesWritten` any number from `0` (timeout) to `dwBytesToWrite` (transmission finished).

Intermediate values means that not all data transferred yet but transmission process can be continued.

Transmission loop might be like this:

```
BYTE *buf = pointer_to_data;
DWORD len = length_of_data;

FT_STATUS status;
DWORD written;

for (;;) {
    status = FT_Write(handle, buf, len, &written);
    if (status != FT_OK)
        return status;
    if (written == 0)
        return -1;   // or FT_OTHER_ERROR if no special timeout handling required
    if (written == len)
        return FT_OK;
    len -= written;
    buf += written;
}
```

See also [Example 3, FT2232C Test Application](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CplusplusBuilder.htm) (file t_titan.cpp, function `DoRxTest` at line 289)

Comment: And how much data can I send in one call to FT_Write? 64k, though it depend on the chip and mode. I was able to FT_Write 32k and 48k buffer of bit banging data in one call using my device name Nusbio based on a FT232R.

Answer (score 1):

dwBytesToWrite is a double word, that is 32 bits. A rather large number of bytes to write. My guess is that the function can return FT_OK even if the number of bytes written is < the number of bytes to write. It is useful to know how many bytes have been written, so that the next time you call the function, you know exactly where to set your transmit pointer in the buffer.